# Freezing pageblock header using jQuery- doesnt work on mozilla

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I am freezing the header as explained in this below blog.
[Freezing header -Readkite blog](http://www.redkitetechnologies.com/2013/03/floatingsticky-headers-for-visualforce-pageblocktable)

But the problem i am facing is that i am not able to get it worked on Mozilla.
Do i need to add anything extra? or any CSS ? please help.

Issue i have shown in image.
Header background goes transparent (only in mozilla.)
I am using below jquery code and calling class attribute of pbTable onLoad of page .

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.vfFloatingHeaders = function( options ) {  

    return this.each(function() { 
        try
        {            
            /* Floating table header code */
            //give each table header an ID, since you cant do it in the visualforce code itself, do it via some JS
            $(this).find('.rich-table-thead').each(function(index,value){
                var theadId = Math.floor(Math.random()*10001) + '-' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001) + '-'+Math.floor(Math.random()*10001);
                $(this).attr('randId',theadId);
                $(this).attr('id',theadId);
            });

            //add the floating style to the elements
            if($.browser.mozilla) 
            {

                //table row doeant float in firefox, div floats 
                $(".rich-table-thead" + " tr th div").addClass("floatingStyle"); 



            }   
            else
            { 
                //table row can float in IE and Chrome 
                $(".rich-table-thead"+ " tr th").addClass("floatingStyle"); 


            }

            $(this).parent().scroll(function(){
                $.fn.vfFloatingHeaders.changeFloatingHeaderPosition(this, $($(this).find('.rich-table-thead')[0]).attr('id'));
            });
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            console.log('Error setting up floating header: ' + ex.message);     
        }   
    });

  }; })( jQuery );


$.fn.vfFloatingHeaders.changeFloatingHeaderPosition = function(container, headerId)  { 
    if($.browser.webkit) //chrome rendering bug fix 
    {
        $("#"+headerId + " tr th").css("visibility", "hidden"); 
    }
    if($.browser.mozilla) 
    {
       // alert(container.scrollTop);
        $("#"+headerId + " tr th div").css("top", container.scrollTop-1); 



    }
    else
    {
        $("#"+headerId + " tr th").css("top", container.scrollTop-1); 
    }

    if($.browser.webkit) //chrome rendering bug fix 
    {
        $("#"+headerId + " tr th").css("visibility", "visible");
    }            }

</script>
```

Everything works fine , Except that background going transparent.

Thanks in advance. please help!!![image: Header background tranparent on mozilla :(]

Comment: This seems like a CSS issue specific to the browser; I would recommend asking on StackOverflow or Webmasters.stackexchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CSS and browser-specific problems.

Comment: Thought if someone already had an issue similar to this  and have had some workaround. @MikeChale . Anyways thank you !!